# MVC .NET Passing a ViewBag string[] Array with Jquery Autocomplete to server ActionResult

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to pass a string array saved in a ViewBag back to the server ActionResult via jQuery's autocomplete functionality. I'm doing this to try and persist the data so that I don't have to keep retrieving the prices every time I make a call to the server (prices are retrieved through crawling a url). So here is what I have so far:

The Textbox:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.NewPostModel.NewManualPrice, null, new { @class = "form-control", @type="number", id = "input-post-price", placeholder = "Enter the price" })
```

The Javascript:

```
var priceTags = new Array();
    var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.UrlPrices));
    for(var i =0; i<array.length;i++){ priceTags[i] = array[i]; }  
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#input-post-price").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("PriceSearch", "ModalItem", new { Area = "" } )', { prices: priceTags) }, response);
            }
        });
    })
```

And the ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult PriceSearch(string term, string prices)
        {
            string[] priceList = new string[0];
            if (ViewBag.UrlPrices == null)
                ViewBag.UrlPrices = priceList;
            string[] UrlPrices = ViewBag.UrlPrices; 
            return this.Json(UrlPrices.Where( p => p.StartsWith(term)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The code works fine if I replace the source with :

```
'@Url.Action("PriceSearch", "ModalItem", new { Area = "" } )'
```

and remove the 'string prices' parameter from the actionresult.
But I want to be able to pass the array back as well. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: when you step through the script is your array converting correctly?  you are trying to create an array on the view to send to the controller but your controller has an input of just a string

Comment: Hi Matt, yes i tried both string and string[] but neither one gets triggered. Here's how my javascript gets rendered in Chrome's devtools:



    var priceTags = new Array();
    var array = ["$119.90","$274.75"];
    for(var i =0; i<array.length;i++){ priceTags[i] = array[i]; }  
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#input-post-price").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.getJSON('/Popup/PriceSearch', { prices: priceTags) }, response);
            }
        });
    })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a minor typo, you need to change this:

```
{ prices: priceTags) }
```

To this:

```
{ prices: priceTags }
```

Removing the extra ) bracket

Here is a jsFiddle with an example of passing the data:

http://jsfiddle.net/hutchonoid/wQXJJ/

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work. I ended up passing a string and splitting the string back to its array on the server end.

Comment: No problem, nice one. :)